# Finding the tangent plane on a spiral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> For the spiral 
>   $$r(t) = t \cos(t) \vec{i} + t \sin(t) \vec{j} + t \vec{k}$$
>
> find the equation of the tangent plane when $t = \frac{k\pi}{3}$ for $k = 1,2,3$.
>   Also determine if the planes intersect and where.

My strategy is to first find the direction vector at the given points and to find its normal vector.

I'm a bit iffy regarding how to proceed from there...

Once I can get the planes equation I think I can solve for the intersections.

Can I have some help?

Comment: paths generally only have tangent vectors rather than tangent planes. This path exists entirely on the surface $x^2+y^2=z^2$  this surface would certainly have tangent planes at the specified points.

Comment: I think it should be the tangent *line* or the *normal* plane to the curve.

Comment: I see.  The problem clearly states planes so I would like to assume that it's talking about normal planes.  Could you help me out in that case @A.G. ?